# error when installing/configuring graphite on ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, sqlite, graphite

I am setting up graphite on ubuntu 13.  I uncommented the sqlite3 option from the local_settings.py file in /opt/graphite/webapp/graphite and tried running the syncdb command but observed the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 152, in __init__
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

Should I simply setup credentials for sqlite3 or is the issue related to some other misconfiguration.  Thanks!

Update:
Unless I am mistaken - A username/password is not supported by the sqlite/sqlite3 package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the following seems to have solved the issue for me:

I added the secret key in the app_settings.py file in /opt/graphite/webapps/graphite.  I was able to add a superuser (after running syncdb after that).

Answer (score 2):

You [have to add](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#secret-key)

```
SECRET_KEY = 'some_random_secret_string'
```

to your django settings file.

Comment: are you referring to settings.py or local_settings.py (for graphite)

Comment: @alihaider If your `settings.py` is django settings file, this place seems more appropriate to me. However, I think `local_settings.py` will do also (as they are imported in django settings).

Comment: Adding your settings to local_settings.py will make sure they settings are kept if during an upgrade. The graphite-web package will modify settings.py on upgrade.